# Must SignalR HubConnection.CreateHubProxy() need to be called after EnsureReconnecting?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

After SignalR disconnects due to connection error, the state is `Disconnected` and `EnsureReconnecting()` may be called to attempt to reconnect. If the reconnect is successful, will the previous proxies still be valid? Or do I need to recreate them using `CreateHubProxy()`?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the proxy will still be valid as EnsureReconnecting doesn't do much according to the code: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/3a219c101587333d562f04f30903d50ad9773e1c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/ConnectionExtensions.cs